# Allow mock location for non-onwer user

Tags: geolocation, location-services

Is there a way to enable mock location on a non-owner user?  I have a test user account on my Android device to test a line of business app and need to be able to test location awareness without actually having to be at each of the locations.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!